# NASM assembled binary works, but shellcode in C causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm, shellcode

I am trying to learn about assembly and shellcode. I am having a problem that has been driving me nuts for days. I have written some assembly to make a system call to execve. The assembled file works, but when I convert it to shellcode and try to run it from a C program, I get a segmentation fault. I have tried all sorts of variations, but nothing works. Currently, the nasm code is as follows:

```
global _start

section .data
    cmd: db '/bin/netcat', 0
    argv0: db 'netcat', 0
    argv1: db '127.0.0.1', 0
    argv2: db '3333', 0
    argv: dd argv0, argv1, argv2, 0

section .text
_start:
    mov ebx, cmd ; filename parameter
    mov ecx, argv ; argv parameter
    xor edx, edx ; envp parameter
    mov al, 11 ; execve system call number. Moving to al rather than eax to prevent null bytes in shellcode.
    int 0x80

    ; exit
    xor ebx, ebx ; status code 0
    mov al, 1 ; sys_exit
    int 0x80
```

I assembled this with the following command:

```
nasm -f elf32 test.asm -o test.o && ld -m elf_i386 test.o -o test
```

Running test works fine. I obtained the shellcode from test using the command from [this page](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/6051/get-all-shellcode-on-binary-file-from-objdump) and of course, replacing ./PROGRAM with ./test.

Finally, I have the following C code:

```
unsigned char[] = "\xbb\x98\x90\x04\x08\xb9\xba\x90\x04\x08\x31\xd2\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xcd\x80";

main()
{
    int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;
    ret();
}
```

Compiled with:

```
gcc -g -m32 -fno-stack-protector -z execstack testshellcode.c -o testshellcode
```

Running testshellcode results in a Segmentation fault. I have tried various things like making code a const, compiling with different flags, and about 1,000 variations of the nasm code. I have successfully run other shellcode that calls execve, but argv was simple in those cases.

Using gdb, I can see it crashes when ret() is called. Looking at the registers after the segmentation fault:

```
eax 0xffffffda -38
ecx 0x80490ba 134516922
edx 0x0 0
ebx 0x0 0
esp 0xbffff14c 0xbffff14c
ebp 0xbffff178 0xbffff178
eip 0x804a03a 0x804a03a <code+22>
eflags 0x10246 [ PF ZF IF RF ]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: At least three problems: 1) you didn't include the data in your shellcode 2) said data contains zero bytes 3) your code is not position independent.

Comment: @Jester (2) may or may not actually be a problem depending on what the OP is trying to learn here.

Comment: @immibis true, apparently the C standard allows embedded zero bytes in literals.

Comment: You can't use a `.data` section when trying to generate shell code. As Jester points out that doesn't allow it to be position independent. Shell code needs to run entirely from the stack to work as expected. To embed strings in shell code and make it available on the stack can usually be done via the jump/call/pop method. You can see this [video](http://www.pentesteracademy.com/video?id=275&utm_source=HT&utm_medium=facebook&utm_campaign=DSM) to get an idea how that technique works.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I have switched to that method, but now I have a new set of problems :-) Upon examination of memory, everything looks goods but execve does nothing. I will update my post in a moment.